# SingleValueArrayConverter of an array returning null properties

Tags: c#, json, serialization

I'm trying to use a custom singlearrayconverter to access the values of my json array, but I keep getting null values, I'm wondering where I could be doing something wrong.

I have the following JSON:

```
{
  "message": "success",
  "action": "user_info",
  "data": {
    "profile_info": {
      "querying": "0",
      "tps": {
        "1": {
          "profile_url": "anotherfakeurl",
          "file_hash": "hash",
          "icon_path": "",
          "time_of_insertion": "0000-00-00 00:00:00",
          "tp_id": "1",
          "user_id": "4",
          "tp_user_id": "1377839182243200",
          "last_use": "0000-00-00 00:00:00",
          "active": "0",
          "user_display": "it's a me",
          "selected": "1",
          "prof_pic": "fakeurl"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And I have the following datamodel:

```
[JsonProperty("tps")]
[JsonConverter(typeof(SingleValueArrayConverter<Tps>))]
public List<Tps> TpsList { get; set; }
```

And I'm using this converter:

```
public class SingleValueArrayConverter<T> : JsonConverter
    {
        public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }



public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        object retVal = new Object();
        if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.StartObject)
        {
            T instance = (T)serializer.Deserialize(reader, typeof(T));
            retVal = new List<T>() { instance };
        }
        else if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.StartArray)
        {
            retVal = serializer.Deserialize(reader, objectType);
        }
        return retVal;
    }

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

And every other value is correct, it even gives me the right array count. But the contents of each Tps property are either empty or null.

Thank you,

edit: Here is the full Data Model.

```
[JsonObject(MemberSerialization = MemberSerialization.OptIn)]
    public class UserInfo
    {
        [JsonProperty("message")]
        public string Message { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("action")]
        public string Action { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("data")]
        public Data Data { get; set; }
}


public class Data
    {

        [JsonProperty("profile_info")]
        public ProfileInformation ProfileInformation { get; set; }
    }

public class ProfileInformation
    {
    [JsonProperty("querying")]
        public string Querying { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("tps")]
        [JsonConverter(typeof(SingleValueArrayConverter<Tps>))]
        public List<Tps> TpsList { get; set; }
    }

public class Tps
    {
    [JsonProperty("profile_url")]
        public string ProfileUrl { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("file_hash")]
        public string FileHash { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("icon_path")]
        public string IconPath { get; set; }

        [JsonIgnore]
        [JsonProperty("time_of_insertion")]
        public DateTime TimeOfInsertion { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("tp_id")]
        public int TpId { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("user_id")]
        public int UserId { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("tp_user_id")]
        public long TpUserId { get; set; }

        [JsonIgnore]
        [JsonProperty("last_use")]
        public DateTime LastUse { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("active")]
        public string Active { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("user_display")]
        public string UserDisplay { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("selected")]
        public string Selected { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("prof_pic")]
        public string ProfilePicture { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Share Tps source. CanConvert returns false always

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not saying this is the most elegant or best way around, but it works. You can use a dictionary to achieve the desired bahavior. So, **lose the converter**, then move back and forth between a list and a dictionary, key being that `TpId` field it seems.

```
public class ProfileInformation
{
    [JsonProperty("querying")]
    public string Querying { get; set; }

    List<Tps> _tpsList = null;
    [JsonIgnore]        
    public List<Tps> TpsList {
        get {
            if (_tpsList == null && _tpsDict != null) {
                _tpsList = _tpsDict.Values.ToList();
            }                    
            return _tpsList; 
        }
        set { _tpsList = value; }
    }

    Dictionary<int, Tps> _tpsDict = null;
    [JsonProperty("tps")]
    public Dictionary<int, Tps> TpsDict { 
        get {
            if (_tpsDict == null && _tpsList != null) {
                _tpsDict = _tpsList.ToDictionary(x => x.TpId);
            }
            return _tpsDict;
        }
        set { _tpsDict = value; }
    }
}
```

Test

```
var userInfo = new UserInfo() {
            Action = "user_info",
            Message = "success",
            Data = new Data() {
                ProfileInformation = new ProfileInformation() {
                    Querying = "0",
                    TpsList = new List<Tps>() {
                        new Tps() {
                            Active="0",
                            FileHash = "hash",
                            IconPath="",
                            LastUse= DateTime.MinValue,
                            ProfileUrl = "anotherfakeurl",
                            ProfilePicture = "fakeurl",
                           Selected = "1",
                           TimeOfInsertion = DateTime.MinValue,
                           TpId = 1,
                           TpUserId = 1377839182243200L,
                           UserDisplay = "it's a me",
                           UserId = 4
                        } } } } };

    string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(userInfo, Formatting.Indented);
    var newUserInfo = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<UserInfo> (json);
    Assert.AreEqual(newUserInfo.Data.ProfileInformation.TpsList.Count,1);
    Assert.AreEqual(newUserInfo.Data.ProfileInformation.TpsDict.Count,1);
```